# make4ht compiled HTML math doesn't justify with text

Tags: line-breaking, tex4ht, html, mathjax, make4ht

My test.tex MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a aliquam nisi, eu efficitur erat. Vivamus sagittis quis erat ut volutpat. Pellentesque venenatis convallis dignissim. Integer ullamcorper dolor et ornare sodales.

\par The visible samples of the input are $x_s(t) = 0.5\delta(t) -2.8\delta(t-ts) + 1.3\delta(t-2ts)+ 3.5\delta(t-3ts) -1.7\delta(t-4ts) + 1.1\delta(t-5ts) + 4\delta(t-6ts)$. 
Their corresponding output values are $x[n] = 0.5\delta[n] -2.8\delta[n-1] + 1.3\delta[n-2]+ 3.5\delta[n-3] -1.7\delta[n-4] + 1.1\delta[n-5] + 4\delta[n-6]$.

\end{document}
```

When I compile using 'pdflatex test.tex' I got everything justified because the math is breaking in two lines:

[image: pdflatex output]

But when compiling with 'make4ht test.tex -c make4ht.cfg -d html "mathml, mathjax"', the HTML output is like that:

[image: HTML output]

The make4ht.cfg file used is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701927/308422), with some CSS modifications:

```
\Preamble{xhtml} 

% Fix math input errors when using mathml + mathjax + amsmath packages
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{qopname}
   {\Configure{mathop}{*}
      {<\a:mathml mtext \mml:class="qopname">}
  {</\a:mathml mtext><mo> &\#x2061;<!--FUNCTION APPLICATION--> </mo>}
      {}}
\catcode`\:=12

\Css{body{  
    text-align: justify;
    margin:40px auto;  
    max-width:36em;  
    line-height:1.5;  
    font-size: 0.88em;  
    color:\#222;  
    background-color:\#FEFEF7;  
    padding:0 10px;}}  

\begin{document} 

\EndPreamble
```

There is any way to fix the HTML output?

Comment: mathjax doesn't linebreak inline math as far as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

Line breaking in MathML doesn't work correctly, both in [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=534962) and in [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2312). Version 4 of MathJax should [support linebreaking](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/releases/tag/4.0.0-alpha.1#linebreaking), but I cannot get it to work.

You can try it the beta version of MathJax 4 with this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Fix math input errors when using mathml + mathjax + amsmath packages
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{qopname}
   {\Configure{mathop}{*}
      {<\a:mathml mtext \mml:class="qopname">}
  {</\a:mathml mtext><mo> &\#x2061;<!--FUNCTION APPLICATION--> </mo>}
      {}}
\catcode`\:=12

\Css{body{  
    text-align: justify;
    margin:40px auto;  
    max-width:36em;  
    line-height:1.5;  
    font-size: 0.88em;  
    color:\#222;  
    background-color:\#FEFEF7;  
    padding:0 10px;}}  

\Configure{MathJaxSource}{https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@4.0.0-beta.4/tex-mml-chtml.js}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Link to the beta version is given in the `MathJaxSource` configuration.

It adds a new menu when you right click on the math content, suggesting that line breaking should work:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to do anything, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried V 4 beta of mathjax, using the command you showed above. Tried it on small document. Found V 3 is much better. in V 3.0, fonts are darker, more crisp, easier to read,  and do not have small variation in weight. Also I see some letters have extra trailing _ at the end for some reason in V 4. I guess because this is still beta. Here is screen shot https://12000.org/tmp/mathjax_4_beta/mathjax_V4_beta_vs_V3.png so you can see. Will try again whenever the final V 4 is out. This is one Brave browser. I should try other browsers to see if that makes difference.

Comment: @Nasser I guess these things  can change in the released version, hopefully :)